# HTML head area validation

Tags: html, syntax, doctype, head

I'm taking a basic javascript class, pretty straightforward..except my teacher gave me this feedback on my last assignment:

Note their are some html validation errors with your head area in your html - you may have deductions for html syntax errors in future assignments.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>myTitle</title>
    <h3 class = "Heading">myHeading</h3>    
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "cssFile.css" >
</head>
```

I don't quite understand, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input
enter your code there and you'll see a lot of 11 errors and 2 warnings. Your heading goes in the body not in your head.

This alone removes six of your errors (errors are still present, you need to run your code into the above link).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>myTitle</title>   
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "cssFile.css" >
</head>
<body>
<h3 class = "Heading">myHeading</h3> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: In addition to the syntax errors, there’s also the structural error (somewhat debatable, and not detected in validation) of using `h3` for something that seems to be the main heading, i.e. the 1st leveö, which should be `h1`. The font size of a heading should be set using CSS, not by the choice of heading level.